# Yum not calculating entire dependency tree

Tags: rpm, yum

Let's pretend I have a small set of rpm dependencies like this:

```
  A
 / \
B ->C
```

So A needs B and C, B needs C, C is alone.

In the rpm I can specify these dependencies and when I install A it will also install B and C, however it seems to do it in a somewhat random order, sometimes It will do B first and sometimes C. If it does B first we might get an error because C does not exist yet.

So the RPM gives me the ability to set an order. But what if my graph is not so simple? What if it's 200 rpms with a maze of dependencies all rooted to a top level master package? Having developers need to manually manage the order seems futile.

Is there a way to force yum to calculate the entire tree and start installing from the lowest leaves first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the required packages are runtime libraries, etc, so the order isn't too important. But there is a lesser used option to the `Requires` tag where you can say if you actually need the other RPM for your `%pre` stage - it's simply `Requires(pre)`.

However, when using this, the dependent RPM [*can* later be removed](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Dependencies) if you don't also have a 'regular' `Requires` as well!